# Как перевести текст из одной раскладки в другую ("Home" --> "Рщьу")

Tags: c#, .net

Есть слово на английском **Home** его нужно перевести в слово **Рщьу**.

Т.е. перевести из английской раскладки в русскую. Понятно, что для двух раскладок можно составить словарь перевода.

Есть ли готовые инструменты для нескольких раскладок?

Например для следующих переводов:

EN > RU

RU > EN

ES > EN

EN > ES

JA > EN

ZH > EN

AR > EN

Comment: Есть WinAPI функция MapVirtualKeyEx, посмотрите в ее сторону

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ToUnicode(uint virtualKeyCode, uint scanCode,
        byte[] keyboardState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        StringBuilder receivingBuffer, int bufferSize, uint flags);

static char GetChar(char key)
{
    bool isUpper = char.IsUpper(key);
    var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];

    ToUnicode((uint)char.ToUpper(key), 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
    return isUpper ? char.ToUpper(buf[0]) : buf[0];    
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "Home";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(GetChar(str[i]));
    }
}
```

Для русского языка выведет: **Рщьу**

Answer (score 2):

Пример (но может я не понял сути вопроса):

```
using System.Globalization; //пространство имен для использования языков
 InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

Eng `"en-US"`